# Element style not allowed as child of element body in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

Tags: html, css, styles, validation

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>assignment 4</title>
        <h1>Assignment4- CSS basics</h1>

 <style>
.special
{
text-align:justify;
text-indent:10px;
}
```

**Its telling me that the element style is not allowed, please help**

Answer (score 4):

The `h1` does not belong in the `head` section. Instead, it should be in the `body`.

It should look something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <title>assignment 4</title>
      <style>
         .special {
             text-align:justify;
             text-indent:10px;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Assignment4- CSS basics</h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually, the `<head>` tag contains _nothing but_ HTML markup, just like the rest of an HTML document. :)

Comment: @SLaks You're right, I was just thinking about how I worded that.

Answer (score 4):

`<h1>` (like other content elements) cannot appear in the `<head>` tag.
Therefore, the parser assumes that you closed the `<head>` and started the `<body>`.

`<style>` tags can *only* appear in the `<head>` tag.
Since the parser earlier implicitly started the `<body>`, you get an error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the head section before including any HTML content. The css should appear within the head section but the H1 tag within the body. 
ie.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>assignment 4</title>
<style>
.special
{
   text-align:justify;
   text-indent:10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Assignment4- CSS basics</h1>
</body>
</html>
```